# issue with CSS background-position right in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, background-image

i have the following code:

```
<p class="more"><a href="/stories" class="more">Read more</a></p>
```

and CSS:

```
a.more, a.back { padding: 0px 20px 2px 4px;}
a.more {background: url(../images/ui/arrowLeftBlue.gif) 100% 3px no-repeat;}
```

for some reason - when i [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/a7vPK/1/) it - it works.
but when i view it in IE9 - the background image doesn't show on the right of the link.
interestingly in IE8 - it shows fine.

here's a screenshot first in IE9 and then in IE8:

URL: http://bit.ly/wBsMBj

Thanks!

Comment: The image shows for me in IE9 just fine, I think. Perhaps a cache issue?

Comment: weird - i even tried to view the site via Adobe BrowserLab - even there it didnt show the image.

Re the questions  - thanks, i'll check

Comment: It has something to do with the background-position of 100% combined with the RTL and text-align left on the `p`, messing up the positioning in IE9. Not entirely sure what's behind all of this though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - found the correct solution:

for some reason, the left-aligned paragraph needed to NOT have any padding in it. so i replaced the padding for margin instead.

then the BG image on the anchor kicked in.
not sure why, but it works.

thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's due to the `..` in the background URL. I guess IE9 start searching from the document itself while other browsers start searching from the style sheet file. So, IE9 simply can't find the file.

To solve this mess just use such path instead:

```css
background: url(/images/ui/arrowLeftBlue.gif);
```

Next time, please post your real code to save people the need to view your source of the live site. :)

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard - i made the change you suggested, but there is no change.

Comment: OK - found the correct solution:

for some reason, the left-aligned paragraph needed to NOT have any padding in it. so i replaced the padding for margin instead. 

then the BG image on the anchor kicked in.
not sure why, but it works.

thanks anyway for the help. 

 This comment should be marked as the answer.